# Making fictional "people" using random, getting lots of clones (PHP, Mysql)

Tags: php, mysql, random

So, I'm trying to make a gladiator game, where the players will be lanistas. I'm going for realism, so the gladiators will die in the arena, making a big influx of new "recruits" necessary.

For now, each newly created gladiator has 21 attributes, ranging from numerical values for things such as strength and agility, to text for faction and name. These are calculated by random functions. Names and factions I'm picking randomely from arrays with (at least for names) a relatively big list of realistic names. Numerical values are simply rand(x,y).

Before I added the name and faction arrays, I tried several times running the file that create gladiators with a while loop creating 10000 gladiators, without any clones emerging, as far as I could see. Now, with picking names too from random (as described above), everything works fine if I create a small number of gladiators, but once I use a number of a couple of hundred for my while loop, or if I run the file a few times in a row with as low a number as 50 in my while loop, I get clones.

With 21 attributes, 100 different values+ for most of them, getting clones doesn't happen by chance. Can anyone tell me what's wrong? This can kill my game, and I was just getting optimistic after overcoming a few (easy) challenges.

Oh, and yeah, the gladiators with the attributes are put into a mysql database automatically.

**Edit (update):**
I went back in my stuff, removed the naming and faction random functions, and set all to "s". Created 10000 gladiators named s s from faction s, and it seems there are excactly 0 clones - nobody with the exact same stats.

Reactivated the random name functions. Ran the file, creating 200 gladiators. Couldn't see clones. Ran it again. One clone for each gladiator. And again. Now two clones for the gladiators.

This random function isn't random at all, is it?

**Edit (update 2):**
Tested it again, with one of the previously excluded random functions activated one at a time. It seems its the firstname and surname functions that are screwing things up. Also, from my last test, it seems like there's a pattern, with gladiator id 209 being equal to 737, 77 being equal to 605 and 1133, 148 equal to 676, 772 equal to 244, and so on.

737-209, 605-77, 1133-605, 676-148, 772-244 all have one thing in comon. They all equal 528.

This isn't much random at all.

The function I use for getting names goes something like:

```
$surname=surname($faction) //surname is a function, using the variable $faction

function surname($faction) {
if ($faction=="Roman") {
$nomen = array("Aburius", "Accius", [...]);
$cognomen = array("Zeno", "Zonsimus", [...]);
$randnomen=array_rand($nomen,1);
$randcognomen=array_rand($cognomen,1);
$merge=array($nomen[$randnomen],$cognomen[$randcognomen]);
$surname=implode(" ",$merge);
return $surname;
}
```

To clarify: The [...] in the $nomen and $cognomen arrays is there in place of hundreds of roman names, to save space and your time.

Comment: Random is random. As long as you aren't preventing it, there will be a possibility of randomly generating the same gladiator twice, regardless of how many possible combinations there are.

Comment: You need to show code, but I would make a `UNIQUE` index on your table you are inserting into with what ever columns you want to define that gladiator as unique

Comment: It's hard to guess why without seeing the code, but are you seeding the random number generator more than once?

Comment: When you say clone, do you mean, same name, or same everything across the board. If same everything, there's probably a logic error involved.

Comment: we need to see some code before we can tell you where you're going wrong. It does indeed sound like a programming error somewhere, if you're getting exact matches so frequently.

Comment: Here is the code for the name generation for roman nominal and congominal names: 
function surname($faction) {
    if ($faction=="Roman") {
        $nomen = array("Aburius", "Accius");
        $cognomen = array("Zeno", "Zonsimus");
        $randnomen = array_rand($nomen,1);
        $randcognomen = array_rand($cognomen,1);
  //      echo $nomen[$rand_keys[0]] . "\n";
  //      echo $nomen[$rand_keys[1]] . "\n";
        $merge=array($nomen[$randnomen],$cognomen[$randcognomen]);
        $surname=implode(" ",$merge);
        return $surname;

(Removed a load of names cause chars to many for post)

Comment: What is your uniqueness criteria? What makes a gladiator a clone of another? It is not clear on your question

Comment: You can edit your post with code.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. A clone is excactly the same. The same first name, the same surname, the same exact stats for every other stat. See my answer below for more details.

Comment: Tried editing my text with code. Was told it wasn't code. So, meh.

Sorry for not doing this properly, I'm pretty much a total newb at programming, taught by youtube and random googling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`array_rand` seems to have a problem with randomness see [**here**](https://www.php.net/array_rand).

I prefer to use [**mt_rand**](https://www.php.net/mt_rand) myself.

The following function can create random names with either1,2 or three parts.

```
function randomName(){
    $numargs = func_num_args();
    $first = func_get_arg(0);
    $one = count($first)-1;
    $name = $first[mt_rand( 0,$one)]; //count($array)-1 
    if($numargs > 1){
        $middle = func_get_arg(1);
        $two = count($middle)-1;
        $name .=" ". $middle[mt_rand( 0,$two)];
    }   
    if($numargs > 2){
        $last = func_get_arg(2);
        $three = count($last)-1;
        $name .= " ".$last[mt_rand( 0,$three)];
    }
    return $name;
}
```

USE

```
$var= randomName($first,$middle,$last);// 3 names
$var= randomName($first,$last);// 2 names
etc
```

WHERE $first,$middle,$last are arrays

Comment: Thanks a bunch, it seems the mt_rand did the trick!

Even after changing my random name function to a variant very close to yours, I got stat-clones, but they had unique names. Then I tried using rseed for the rand functions for stats, but still got stat clones. Took me a while, but finally I realized I could use mt_rand for my random stat functions too, and now it seems all my clones are gone.

Thanks man. Would vote up if I had the required amount of reputation :)

Comment: Glad to be of help. You can accept the Answer if you like

Comment: My function occasionally produces the same names but the larger the arrays the less this happens.

Comment: By the way: Do you happen to know if there are any php random functions with normal distribution and other types of distributions other than the even distribution that you get from mt_rand?

Comment: @JohnKohan I have a normal distribution function. email me (see profile)

Answer (score 0):

With only ~100 values for an attribute and 1000s of gladiators, there may be many with the same name attribute, for example.

If you mean that there may be multiple gladiators where all 21 attributes are the same, then the only way to guard against that is to check newly created gladiators against the existing ones and if there is a match regenerate the new one.

Just like you would when someone registers for a site, normally username and email address must be unique per user, so you have to check first.

The easiest and most performant in this case might be to generate a "hash" of each gladiator's properties and check if it exists before generating a new gladiator.  This will make them all unique, so you also need to consider how unique do you want them?  Can 2 or more gladiators have 20 properties in common?  How about 15, etc?

Comment: Thanks for answer. The problem is that EVERYTHING is the same with the clones. Example: Out of 9901 created gladiators now from my 9900 while loop, there are 46 with this exact information:
Potitus Caesulenus Adranos 0.54 loyalty, 0.13 happiness, 1.46 morale, 0.85 strength, 5.97 agility, 2.32 stamina, 0.51 quickness, 103 intelligence, 143 height, 2.77 attackskill, 0.04 defenceskill, 1609 age, 2.3 appearance, 0.86 charisma, faction roman.

Currently only 18 different random stats, with an average of ~100-500 different values for each stat. The probability of a clone is ~0 if truly random.

Comment: How would I make a check, and how much slower would that make the program? It seems like a pretty awful random function in php. A check shouldn't even be necessary. I guess the biggest issue to check would be the names though. And I guess I can most effectively make a check to stop clones by using some sort of average rating stat that combines all other stats to one.

Comment: I have a "gladiatorid" stat for every gladiator in my database, which autoincrements and can be used for some check loop. How would I go about checking my database for lets say `avgstat` for each gladiator (or, even better, only the newly created)?